# Installing CUDA Toolkit 11 when your computer CUDA version says 10.1

Tags: windows-10, gpu, cuda

I suspect that CUDA is not installed in my windows 10 machine, so I am planning to download and install it. For that I would use [this link](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads) that allows me to get CUDA Toolkit 11.

However if I do nvidia-smi I get

```
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVSMI\nvidia-smi.exe"
Sun Aug 02 11:38:02 2020
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 432.18       Driver Version: 432.18       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name            TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1050   WDDM  | 00000000:02:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   34C    P8     8W /  N/A |     68MiB /  2048MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

which indicates that the GPU driver is installed for 10.1

My question is, can I install safely the version 11?

EDIT' Following the advice I updated the driver and now I got

```
Sun Aug 02 22:23:17 2020                                                                                                
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+                                         
| NVIDIA-SMI 432.18       Driver Version: 451.77       CUDA Version: 11.0     |                                         
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+                                         
| GPU  Name            TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |                                         
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |                                         
|===============================+======================+======================|                                         
|   0  GeForce GTX 1050   WDDM  | 00000000:02:00.0 Off |                  N/A |                                         
| N/A   38C    P8     8W /  N/A |     68MiB /  2048MiB |      0%      Default |                                         
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+                                         
                                                                                                                        
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+                                         
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |                                         
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |                                         
|=============================================================================|                                         
|  No running processes found                                                 |                                         
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Next I suppose it will be to install CUDA 11

Answer (score 0):

You can almost certainly *install* version 11, but you will likely end up falling back to only being able to use version 10 features or have some functionality missing.

If possible you should update your graphics driver.

From [Cuda Toolkit Release Notes](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html)

[image]